# Retina display image quality problem

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, retina-display

I was trying to make my OPENGL ES app to support for retina display. I've added the image with @2x extension and made the contentscale factor to 2. The high resolution image is coming in the screen correctly but it suffers great loss of quality. The edges and blurred and it doesn't have quality of image I added into the resource folder.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you test it on real retina device or simulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My app is based on the default framework and I was getting this issue when running on a Retina based device.  Specifically my framebuffer was being created at 320x480 rather than 640x960 as I wanted. Sorry James but this is NOT automatic because the problem is with the framebuffer created by [renderBufferStorage:fromDrawable:](http://developerns.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/EAGLContext_ClassRef/Reference/EAGLContext.html) (which calls glRenderbufferStorage on our behalf but specifies layout pixels rather than native device pixels for width and height by default).

I added the following code below line lines which set **eaglLayer.drawableProperties** in **initWithCoder:** in **EAGLView.m**:

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
if ([mainScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
{
    // iOS 4.0 and up (further to simeon's comment)
    const CGFloat scale = mainScreen.scale;
    self.contentScaleFactor = scale;
    eaglLayer.contentsScale = scale;
}
```

Thanks to David Amador's [post](http://www.david-amador.com/2010/09/setting-opengl-view-for-iphone-4-retina-hi-resolution/) for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks, more recently, to simeon's helpful comments.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest checking explicitly for retina dimensions as this doesn't work in all cases (e.g., retina iPad). See my answer below for a more general solution that uses the screen's scale factor.

Comment: You don't need the `else` branch because there are no retina pre-iOS 4.0 devices, so if mainScreen does not respond to the `scale` selector, you can be sure that it's non-retina.

Comment: You raise a very interesting point. I guess that API had to be introduced for Retina devices and, thus, must be present on them! Thanks simeon. I shall update again. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your EAGLView.m initWithCoder: method, add the following code:

```
if( [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] )
{
    self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

OpenGLES will be rendered at the greatest possible resolution on the retina display automatically (given you've set your viewport to the width and height of the screen, etc. etc.) so the problem comes from your OpenGL rendering.

OpenGLES doesn't care about the suffix @2X you've appended to the image (this is for Cocoa Touch frameworks). It does, however, care about the resolution of the image. For the best results, you should use square images that are a width and height that is a power of two (e.g. 1024, 2048 etc.).

You should ensure that when you're loading the texure into OpenGLES that you're using the correct image format, and that you're not compressing it in any way.

The other thing you should experiment with is the texture parameters. For example:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi thankx for the help. But even after trying what you said, itz not showing the quality. Can you please tell me how to know whether the image is compressed or not? Will I get any better results if I use Multisampling??

Comment: Can you add some code to your question that gives the jist of how you load in the texture into OpenGLES? I don't think you'll get better results if you use multisampling (this is more of an optimization).